# Как заменить функцию Minimize в Mathcad?

Tags: математика, mathematica

Дискретизированный сигнал y(xn)=yn; (n=0; N-1) задан значениями в таблице:
x=0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1; 1.2; 1.4; 1.6; 1.8;
y= -0.8; -0.6; 0.2; 0.7; 0.9; 1.4; 0.8; 0.4; 0.1; -0.2;

Нужно провести сглаживание (апроксимацию) данных с помощью полинома Pi(x)=a0+a1x;

Собственно задача решена. Но в решении невидно логики решения...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть функция Minimize(s, a0, a1), её нужно заменить на "раскрытое" полное решение. С этим и нужна ваша помощь.

п.с. по идее, там должна быть система уравнений и её нужно решить.

Comment: Вы сами метод наименьших квадратов написать не можете, или просто не понимаете откуда систему уравнений брать?

Comment: Логика с мат точки зрения довольно проста. Мы взяли выражение по которому оцениваем отклонение, оно - s(a0, a1). Функция minimize просто ищет нижний экстремум. Чтобы сделать без нее, в нашем простом случае нам достаточно взять частную производную s(a0, a1) сначала по a0 (первый параметр) и приравнять ее к нулю, потом так же по второму параметру. Отсюда получаем систему уравнений и решаем ее. Имплементировать это в маткаде мне лень, и вообще я не оч уверен что здесь такая добрая душа найдется, итак вопрос на грани фола.

Comment: В обещм надо врубиться вот в это: http://www.cleverstudents.ru/articles/mnk.html

Comment: @ru_volt спасибо.